# Launch an activity from TileService for Android 14 is not allowed

Tags: android, android-intent, tile-service

I have a simple `TileService` and try to launch an activity by click on the tile. It is works on Android 13 and low but in Android 14 I get an exception:

*startActivityAndCollapse: Starting activity from TileService using an Intent is not allowed.*

How to fix it?

Comment: Could you give a short example of using TileService#startActivityAndCollapse(PendingIntent pendingIntent)? I'm facing the same issue and not able to figure out the transition from Intent to PendingIntent. Thank you :)

Comment: @KKH startActivityAndCollapse( PendingIntent.getActivity

Comment: I used the same approach: `startActivityAndCollapse(PendingIntent.getActivity(applicationContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)`, but the Logcat keeps giving the `Input dispatching timed out ...` error, which didn't exist when using `startActivityAndCollapse(intent)` in API 33 and below.

Comment: @KKH try to add flag PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the source code of [TileService.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/service/quicksettings/TileService.java).
And [here is the documentation of startActivityAndCollapse(Intent intent)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/quicksettings/TileService#startActivityAndCollapse(android.content.Intent)).

Both say you have to use `startActivityAndCollapse(PendingIntent)` because `startActivityAndCollapse(Intent intent)` is deprecated.

You must be using `startActivityAndCollapse(Intent intent)` at the moment because you are getting this error. Use the other one instead.